# In Oracle Apex 18.1, Inteactive grid doesn't show HTML-Expression Column

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am Using `Oracle Application Express 18.1`, and having some troubles using Interactive Grid. I've set Interactive grid that has pagination
(Interactive Grid - Attributes - Pagination - Type : Page).

When its type is Scroll, I can see the HTML-expression column (Pagination - Type : Scroll),
but after I change setting, HTML-Expression column can't show its own value.

Below is Column setting details

```
Column Name : Thumbnail
Type : HTML Expression
Settings : <img src="&IMAGE_URL." width="100px" height="100px" alt="">
```

It should display the image, but It can't.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by : It can't display the image?

What does `&IMAGE_URL.` refers to/what should it contain? 

Have you also looked in the browser's dev console to see if your link is there ?

Comment: Hi, Justin. &IMAGE_URL. is another column in the same interactive grid. It has image url value.

Comment: I would suggest you edit your question to add details : Screenshots of what happens when you mean : "can't display image", exemples of your image URLs. 

For now it's impossible to reproduce your issue as I went through all the same step you mentionned and used your line of code and it worked fine for me.